# Update my contact list when i add a contact with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I add a contact in mysql server with jquery ajax.
But when i add the contact i must refresh my page to 
see the added contact.

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form_contact').on('submit', function() {

    var nom_contact = $('#nom_contact').val();
    var prenom_contact = $('#prenom_contact').val();

    if(prenom_contact == '' || nom_contact == '') {
        alert('Les champs doivent êtres remplis');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.reponse == 'ok') {
                    alert('Tout est bon');
                } else {
                    alert(''+ json.reponse);

                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

my form (with the contact list under the form):

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="contacts">
<h2 class="text-info">Contacts</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form_contact" method="post" action="modif/add_contact.php" >
      <label for="Nom">Nom</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php echo $_GET['modifier'] ?>">
      <input class="span5" type="text" name="nom_contact">

      <label for="Prenom">Prenom</label>
      <input class="span5" type="text" name="prenom_contact">

      <label for="tel">Telephone</label>
      <input class="span5" type="text" name="telephone_contact">

      <label for="desc">Description courte (qui est-ce?)</label>
      <input class="span5" type="text" name="description_contact">

      <input type="submit" name="contact" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Valider" />


</form>
<div id="div_contact">
      <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Prénom</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Télephone</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE id_user = ".$_GET['modifier']."");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
       printf ("
              <tr>
                  <td>".$row["nom_contact"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["prenom_contact"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["description_contact"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["telephone_contact"]."</td>
                  <td><a href='utilisateur.php?modifier=".$_GET['modifier']."&supprimer_contact=".$row[0]."' onclick='return(confirm(\"Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette entrée?\"));'>Supprimer</a></td>


                </tr>
                ");
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>

      </tbody>

    </table>
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: If your answer, "alerting out" correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the ajax success part of your code where you actually add the contact to your list.  The PHP block of code that queries your contact table will only be evaluated when you load the page, which is why it shows up on a refresh of the page but not after an ajax based form submit.